# PHP or SQL count colum elements and separate

Tags: php, mysql

I dont find the sollution, I have a json file (or i have sql table):

```
[{"userid ": 1,"rank": 1}, {"userid ": 1,"rank": 2}]
```

with this colums:

```
userid || rank
1      || 1
1      || 2
1      || 5
2      || 1     
2      || 2
2      || 4
3      || 1
```

I would collect the user ranks, something like this:

```
1 -> 1,2,5
2 -> 1,2,4
3 -> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a SQL database table you could just group the rows and concat the `rank` column:

```
SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(rank)
FROM table
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is JSON you can try something like this:

```
<?php
$json = '[{"userid": 1,"rank": 1}, {"userid": 1,"rank": 2}]';
$ja = json_decode($json);
foreach ($ja as $item) {
    $ranks[$item->userid][] = $item->rank;
}
print_r($ranks);
```

Answer (score 0):

try it in this way `$stack[$userid][]=$rank;`